# JSF validation Message Display in Dialog Box when Button click

Tags: jsf

I need for JSF validation messages displaying in Dialog box when Button is clicked but dialog box should be shown not get hidden.

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <h:panelGrid  columns="1" cellpadding="5">
        <p:commandButton value="Modal" onclick="dlg2.show();" type="button" />
    </h:panelGrid>

<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="200" width="400">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" >
    <p:messages />
    <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{converterBean.doubleValue}" required="true"/>
    <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Submit" action="#{converterBean.submit}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>



    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your case is very similar to [this example from the primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml).

Notice that `<h:form>` is inside `<p:dialog>` there. Also notice in the example's *LoginBean.java* how the callback parameter is set.

Change the `<p:commandButton>` that it updates your `<p:messages>` (it updates a `<p:growl>` in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is an option in  called process, you can process only certain fields
for example what appears below will only submit data under someID only, not the whole entire form

```
        <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Login" widgetVar="dlg" width="600" >

            <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5" id="someID">
                <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username: *" />
                <p:inputText
                    id="username" required="true" label="username" requiredMessage="Field required" />
                <p:message for="username"/>

                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: * " />
                <h:inputSecret
                    id="password" required="true" label="password"  requiredMessage="Field required"  />
                <p:message for="password"/>

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton value="Login" update="display" process="someID" onsuccess="dlg.hide()" onerror="dlg.show()" />
                </f:facet>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>
```